# How to read a value on a specific line in an external file into an AWK script

Tags: input, awk, line, external

Input file:

```
2
5
7
1
2
```

Modifier file (external file):

```
4
6
2
7
9
```

What i want to achieve is, summarizing line1 from input file with line1 from an external file.

AWK script:

```
sum=$1+[value of line 1 on modifier file];
printf("%s\n", sum);
```

expected output:

```
6
11
9
8
11
```

Comment: What is the value of t in your expression?

Comment: can you come up with a simpler example that demonstrates what you want to do? It sounds like the actual problem might be trivial to solve but it's buried in all the current details so some of us might be too lazy to try to figure it out.

Comment: I have an awk filter sample.awk and I print the value Lenght for each row. from an external txt file. But for the time+=(1/50)/('NR=j' rows.txt);, I would like to import values from an another input file called rows.txt

Comment: OK, let's try again. You have some problem you need help with that has something to do with values from 1 file being applied to some value(s) in a different file. What is the simplest possible example you can come up with that demonstrates the problem? Edit your question to show testable sample input and expected output for THAT and you'll get a lot more people trying to help you as it won't be as much effort for them to figure out what it is you want. If you'd started with that you'd almost certainly have the solution by now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{m[NR]=$0;next} {print $0+m[FNR]}' modifierFile inputFile
6
11
9
8
11
```

Comment: My code is more complex and I am also new in awk. Is it possible to use this awk command in a mathematical expression eg. time+=(1/50)/($ awk 'NR==FNR{m[NR]=$0;next} {print $0+m[FNR]}' modifierFile inputFile); ?

Comment: Well, yes kinda maybe but that's absolutely the wrong thing to try to do.

Comment: Maybe try again to provide a simple example that demonstrates your problem if you cant see how to apply this solution to your real problem

Answer (score 0):

Layed down simply what OP wants to do is:

say you want your output file to be like this:

```
words     number1
texts     number2
stuff     number3
things    number4
```

in which case the external file has 4 lines of text which are:

```
number1
number2
number3
number4
```

and the awk script is

```
printf("words ","line one of external file")
printf("texts ","line two of external file")
printf("stuff ","line three of external file")
printf("things ","line four of external file")
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do but I do not know how to print the lines of an external file.

Comment: that's the 3rd time you've used the term "external file". All files are external to an awk script so idk what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
getline valueline < $modfile
```

Comment: No you definitely are not. Make sure you read and fully understand http://awk.info/?tip/getline if you're considering using getline and then, usually, don't.

Comment: Yes, but in this case both files are to be done sequenciel in parallel and is of perhaps very long length. Nice article.